How to solve this problem with jwt token?
In postman I send a get request to http://localhost:8080/auth/signup,
I get
{
"token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzM4NCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJNYWt1c2hldiIsImlhdCI6MTcxODY0NzY5MiwiZXhwIjoxNzE5NTExNjkyLCJlbWFpbCI6ImZmc2Zkc2ZzZnNmc2ZzZEBtYWlsLnJ1In0.VPx-OG ob_24I6IL_lFBn0pdWh6jRcHmJ4JxTVNvn8deALXNOg8uZbeSMa50UeIfC",
"message": "Register Success"
}
Then I send a get request to http://localhost:8080/api/users/12, select Authorization - bearer token, enter this token, but it quits
{
    "timestamp": "2024-06-17T19:23:49.594+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": 
"org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Invalid token …\n\tat com.Makushev.Makushev_Social_Twitter.config.jwtValidator.doFilterInternal(jwtValidator.java:40)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74)\n\tat org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)\n",
    "message": "Invalid token …",
    "path": "/api/users/12"


my AppConfig.java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

        http.sessionManagement(management -> management.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                Authorize -> Authorize
                .requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll())
                .addFilterBefore(new jwtValidator(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .csrf((csrf -> csrf.disable()));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
   

}

my jwtConstant.java
public class JwtConstant {

public static String JWT_HEADER="Authorization";

public static String SECRET_KEY="fasjewjdksnjdbfhbewhfbhewbfhwebfdsbdfdsbfdsnbfnsdbfnewfw";

}

my jwtProvider.java
public class JwtProvider {

    private static SecretKey key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(JwtConstant.SECRET_KEY.getBytes());

    public static String generateToken(Authentication auth) {

        String jwt = Jwts.builder()
                .setIssuer("Makushev") 
                .setIssuedAt(new Date()) 
                .setExpiration(new Date(new Date().getTime() + 864000000)) 
                .claim("email", auth.getName()) 
                .signWith(key) 
                .compact(); 

        return jwt;

    }

    public static String getEmailFromJwtToken(String jwt){

        jwt = jwt.substring(7);

        Claims claims = Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(key).build().parseClaimsJwt(jwt).getBody();

        String email = String.valueOf(claims.get("email"));
        return email;

    } 

my jwtValidator.java
public class jwtValidator extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String jwt = request.getHeader(JwtConstant.JWT_HEADER); 

        if (jwt != null) {

            try {

                String email = JwtProvider.getEmailFromJwtToken(jwt);

                List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

                Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, null, authorities);

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid token …");

            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

    } /
}

my AuthController.java

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public AuthResponse createUser(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception {

        User isExist = userRepository.findUserByEmail(user.getEmail());

        if(isExist!=null) {
            throw new Exception("email already user with another account");
        }

        User newUser = new User();

        newUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        newUser.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
        newUser.setLastName(user.getLastName());
        newUser.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));

        User savedUser = userRepository.save(newUser);

        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(savedUser.getEmail(), savedUser.getPassword());

        String token = JwtProvider.generateToken(authentication);

        AuthResponse res = new AuthResponse(token, "Register Success");

        return res;
    }

    
        /**
         * AutoWired
         */


       private UserService userService;
       private UserRepository userRepository;
       private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public AuthController(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, UserService userService, UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.userService = userService;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }


}

my CustomUserDetailService.java

@Service
public class CustomerUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userRepository.findUserByEmail(username);

        if(user==null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with email " + username);
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), authorities);

        
    /**
     * AutoWired
     */

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CustomerUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }
}enter image description hereenter image description here

I looked at classes with jwt, but couldn't find the error
The following appears in the intellij idea console:
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Invalid token …
    at com.Makushev.Makushev_Social_Twitter.config.jwtValidator.doFilterInternal(jwtValidator.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230) ~[spring-security-config-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]



Writing as a comment since I can't provide a clear answer due to unfamiliarity with Spring/Java. If you place your JWT in this decoder jwt decode you'll get that your hashing algorithm is HS384, while the standard is HS256. Therefore, I'd suggest changing the signWith method, try following the builder at okta dev tutorial with regards to the sign algorithm.

I solved the problem!!!
I had ParseClaimsJwt instead of ParseClaimsJws

lsimonetii, big thanks

You have the Informed badge, but did you visit the [help] ? Note that people with similar problem may find your question so I think you should consider posting an answer.
